# How to change the colors of plots after accessing the figure using plt.gcf()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from fitter import Fitter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

randomData = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

def plotOfFittedDistributions(data):
    f = Fitter(data, distributions=['gamma', "norm", 'invgauss'], timeout=100)
    f.fit()
    f.hist()
    f.plot_pdf()
    ax = plt.gcf()
    return ax

a = plotOfFittedDistributions(data=randomData)

a
```

As can be seen, I accessed the current figure using `plt.gcf()`. Is it possible to change the colors of the plots after accessing then with `plt.gcf()`? So I want to access a single figure with multiple plots after it is created and then change their colors.

Currently I have this, which changes the color but is very 'ugly' code:

```
def colorShift(fig, newColor):
    tracker = []
    for i in range(0, len(fig.gca().get_children())):
        if type(fig.gca().get_children()[i]) == matplotlib.patches.Rectangle:
            tracker.append(i)
        
    for i in tracker[:len(tracker)-1]:
        fig.gca().get_children()[i].set_color(newColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
plt.gca().get_lines()[0].set_color("Purple")
plt.gca().get_lines()[1].set_color("Yellow")
plt.gca().get_lines()[2].set_color("Grey")

myLegend = plt.gca().get_legend()
myLegend.legend_handles[0].set_color('Purple')
myLegend.legend_handles[1].set_color('Yellow')
myLegend.legend_handles[2].set_color('Grey')
```